# Facebook feed dialog posts don't re-share (repost) correctly

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I have facebook feed dialogues successfully setup up for my application using the Facebook UI method, but I'm getting some odd behavior when another user tries to use the "Share" link on Facebook. The content for this re-share is not the same content initially shared and appears to be a snippet of javascript.

This is my current feed dialogue code:

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'feed',
    redirect_uri: link.attr('href'),
    name: "Check out this image on WorkHands",
    picture: link.closest('.thumbnail').find('.featured-image').attr('src'),
    link: link.attr('href'),
    caption: 'Work by' + link.closest('.thumbnail').find('.project-creator').text(),
    description: link.closest('.thumbnail').data('description'),
    display: 'popup'
}
```

Which yields something like this:
[image]

However, as soon as it's shared on Facebook, the dialog looks like this:

[image]

I can only think that this must have something to do with the metatags on the page?
Currently the meta-tags are a little different than the ones being created for the feed dialog:

```
<meta content="103896" property="fb:admins" />
<meta content="WorkHands" property="og:site_name" />
<meta content="website" property="og:type" />
<meta content="Project by Ron Andrade" property="og:title" />
<meta content="https://www.workhands.us/images/78a98834-59fa-48c7-8d93-8ffaa0a75811"    property="og:url" />
<meta content="https://www.workhands.us/assets/work-hands-logo-595.png" property="og:image" />
<meta content="WorkHands is for workers in construction, plumbing, welding, landscaping, electrical, masonry, HVAC, automotive, trucking, and other skilled trades." property="og:description" />
```

Comment: Looks like your page is delivering different content to the FB scraper: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.workhands.us%2Fimages%2F499

Comment: I had similar issue.. My solution is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19741022/facebook-share-post-to-wall-not-displaying-any-image-text-description